# How to test Flask API installed on AWS public EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, server

I just created a public EC2 instance on which I have imported a flask API. My goal here is to test whether the API works well or not. So I run the command `python run.py` on PuTTY which results with this :

```
 * Environment: prod
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Then, I go to my windows command and I try running `curl http://<EC2_public_IP>:5000/` but I get the error `Failed to connect to <EC2_public_IP> port 5000 after 2159 ms: Couldn't connect to server`.

For more context, I show you the security rules on my EC2 instance :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://127.0.0.1` is a loopback address which makes it only accessible from the EC2 instance itself, if you'd like to handle traffic from any source, please change your flask run parameter to handle `0.0.0.0` instead.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```